Latex Hyperlinking on references is suppress on APA7 Document Type
I'm writting a document using apa7 document class (thats a restriction) but having the following issue all my references to any label creates the following warning:

Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing link with empty target on input
line 3.

Afer researching I know that  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}  can fix this issue but I can't have my sections numbered, thats against apa format, here is a small part of the document that have the issue if you want to try:
\documentclass[stu, 12pt, letterpaper, donotrepeattitle, floatsintext, natbib]{apa7}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\useunder{\uline}{\ul}{}
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\title{\Large Título del documento}
\author{Autor(a) \\Autor(a) \\Autor(a)} % (autores separados, consultar al docente)
\course{Código del curso: Nombre del curso}
\professor{Nombre del docente}
\duedate{Fecha}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagenumbering{roman}
\renewcommand\contentsname{\largeÍndice}
\tableofcontents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\newpage
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\largeÍndice de fíguras}
\listoffigures
\newpage
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\largeÍndice de tablas}
\listoftables
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\section{\large Título I}
\noindent \maskCitet{cervantes1999}\\
\label{this_ref}
En un lugar de la Mancha, de cuyo nombre no quiero acordarme, no ha mucho tiempo que vivía un hidalgo de los de lanza en astillero, adarga antigua, rocín flaco y galgo corredor.
\subsection{Título II} 
Una olla de algo más vaca que carnero, salpicón las más noches, duelos y quebrantos los sábados, lantejas los viernes, algún palomino de añadidura los domingos, consumían las tres partes de su hacienda \ref{this_ref}.
\renewcommand\refname{\large\textbf{Referencias}}
\bibliography{mibibliografia}
\end{document}

the logs on the warning part:
tf@toc=\write8
\openout8 = `output.toc'.

[1] (./output.lof
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 1.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 1.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 2.
)
\tf@lof=\write9
\openout9 = `output.lof'.

[2] (./output.lot
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 1.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 1.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 2.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 2.
)
\tf@lot=\write10
\openout10 = `output.lot'.

[3]

Package hyperref Warning: Suppressing empty link on input line 63.


pdfTeX warning (ext4): destination with the same identifier (name{page.1}) has been already used, duplicate ignored
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.66 \newpage
              [1] (./output.bbl) AED endfloat: Processing end Figures and Tables [2

] (./output.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 12.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 13.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 13.
)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-03-14>
 ***********
Package rerunfilecheck Info: File `output.out' has not changed.
(rerunfilecheck)             Checksum: 00F38D97E41A97EE226597D699BFA092;294.
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 25105 strings out of 474104
 462652 string characters out of 5743486
 1929493 words of memory out of 5000000
 47032 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 602349 words of font info for 64 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 99i,12n,107p,438b,463s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmcsc10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmr12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/lm/lmri12.pfb>
Output written on output.pdf (6 pages, 92216 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 81 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 64 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 13 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 37 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)


and the raw compiling logs if needed
https://justpaste.it/8bnr0
Little edit after post: this is happening with Figures, Listings, Tables and sections and all that has a label.

well you have unnumbered sections, so what should \ref do? There is no number to print.

Seems you have not read section 4.4 of the apa7 user manual. Without number to refer to, \ref does not make any sense. You could refer to either the page (\pageref) or the name of the section (\nameref) or something like this.

BTW: Adding formatting commands like \large to the \…name macros is not the best idea, because the macros can be used at several places. Similar with adding \large to the \section command. If all sections should be \large, you should instead redefine the \section command. But doesn't the change of the size also break the apa style?
